# Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture - consolidating business data

Tags: c#, architecture, business-logic

To give you a quick overview of my application architecture, I have the following layers in my application:

- **Domain Model** - Models the problem domain and business rules.
- **Service Model** - Models the service contract consumed by the application.
- **Data Access Layer** - Persistence of domain models, in this case using EF.
- **Services** - Implementations of the service model.
- **Website** - MVC web application.
- **Web API** - RESTful web service API.

Now the problem is that the Web API came later; the MVC web application was the first thing that was built on top of the architecture.

I find myself having to replicate business logic and ViewModels (MVC) and Messages (Web API)...According to the DRY principle, I shouldn't be doing this, so the natural solution is to push the business logic into its own layer which is independent of the application layers.

But...this means that the business logic layer needs it's own set of models which sit between the application layer and the business logic layer. In this respect, it would not be applicable to use domain models, since these really shouldn't ever hit the application layer.

So in short, I'm looking for an industry accepted standard for business logic modelling. Is there an accepted standard for how this should work, and if so, what type of model (i.e. it's not a domain model, and it's not a view model) belongs to the business logic layer?

Comment: "I find myself having to replicate business logic and ViewModels (MVC) and Messages (Web API)..." I really do not get why you would have to duplicate anything really. How adding a Web API has anything to do with business logic? The Web API should just be seen as a port to reach the application service layer over HTTP. ViewModels have nothing do do with application services or web apis, they are UI-related and should live in the Website only (the same goes for any MVC component), it's UI stuff.

Comment: @plalx say for example I want to create a new product in my store. In MVC I have NewProductViewModel and in WebAPI I have NewProductRequestMessage. They both contain the same properties. Both solutions have the same code to persist the information, and return the same responses. DRY has been violated, thus, moving the models and business logic into its own layer and sharing it makes sense, but I was just wondering whether there was a common pattern for this.

Comment: Before the Web API you were supposed to have **View->Controller->Services->Domain Model**. If the web application now uses the web API you can have **View->Controller->Web API->Services->Domain Model**. The View/Controller part can be omitted if your UI doesn't use MVC and the MVC part can either be client-side (SPA) or server-side.

Comment: @plalx what happens if I then want to for argument sake, add a WPF, Windows Forms or Console application that also require the same models and business logic?

Comment: @seriesOne "Both solutions have the same code to persist the information". That makes no sense at all? It seems that you have all these layers but actually do not understand what is their purpose. With the layers you have in place there shouldn't be any duplication at all. The ViewModel is a completely different thing than a DTO returned by the application layer, which is a completely different thing than a domain object. If they accidentally happen to all have the same structure then perhaps that is because you have a simple CRUD application. Nevertheless, they do not have the same purpose.

Comment: @seriesOne It's the same thing... you would have WPF->Services, Windows Forms->Services, or Console->Services. Alternatively, you could even have Console->Web API->Services if you whish the console to consume application services through HTTP.

Comment: You can see the application service layer as the only entry point for every application use cases. This is the only layer that interacts with the domain layer and data access layers (more commonly called the infrastructure layer). Now, you can setup multiple adapters in order to reach the application layer. A Web API is usually just an HTTP adapter allowing to reach application services over HTTP. Alternatively, you could have a Socket adapter, a named pipe adapter or directly call the application services through code if the client is running in the same process.

Comment: The application services are usually returning DTOs. You can either serialize these directly over the wire from the Web API or construct new DTOs from these if you want to decouple the Web API responses from the application layer responses.

Comment: Do you have a better understanding of what I meant now?

Comment: @plalx yes I think so DTOs were what I was missing

Comment: What were you returning from your application services before?

Comment: @plalx repositories returning domain models. Services (in my case things like billing, email, identity) return ServiceResult/s or derivatives. Business logic sits between my repositories & services on one side and client apps on the other. Business Logic is now using DTOs to transform domain models or services results into data that can be pushed/pulled from the client apps. Should the client apps require additional, or client specific data/visualisation, then this is modelled per-client

Comment: @seriesOne By services do you mean the application service layer? There is a huge distinction between application services and domain services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have stumbled upon a contested point of discussion. I myself have struggled with this for a long time.

Object bigots will argue that you shouldn't even have a service layer. Your domain model could then be directly consumed which would eliminate the duplication of logic. Granted, those were the good old days of software modeling. With the advent of the web, apis and SOAs, we are forced to look at alternative ways of modeling our software. Enter **Anemic Domain models**.

Anemic Domain models essentially consist of light weight objects that resemble DTOs more than anything, with underlying services that do the heavy lifting.

The architecture you have described above seems to be a hybrid design. I am guessing by now you must have run into the issue of mapping EF classes to domain objects, which creates yet another layer of objects, unless you use POCOs, in which case you run into namespace issues and what not.

Anyways, I don't think there is an industry standard. What I can tell you is that I have seen a few patterns emerge here and there leaning towards Anemic Domain Models and it's not hard to see why. In disconnected environments (e.g. web, API), complex objects don't work very well, hence the affluence of services.

Since you have layered your application nicely and do not wish to expose your domain model objects, I would suggest using Anemic Models in your service implementations. These would essentially function as DTO objects that can be reused and serialized if the need be, but can also implement basic logic that may even map back to functionality implemented in the services.

On a final note, there is no one-size-fits-all. Use the right tool for the job. Patterns are meant to be guidelines, not step-by-step instructions, so make sure you feel free to tweak them in order to fit your particular needs while retaining the general idea.

You can read more about Anemic Domain Models here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model

Make sure to check out Martin Fowler's objections to Anemic Domain Models as well:
http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html

Comment: Actually, I went for the Rich Domain Model approach, with the philosophy: "Write the code you wish you had". The only major problem I had with this was fully encapsulated collections, which actually has been solved by Jimmy Bogard, but unfortunately, does not work with EF Core (yes, I went bleeding-edge), so until EF Core matures, I've had to sacrifice this...no biggie. Other than that, mapping rich domain models in EF wasn't too bad. - All-in-all, an interesting answer, and thank you!

Comment: "With the advent of the web, apis and SOAs, we are forced to look at alternative ways of modeling our software. Enter Anemic Domain models." This answer is very wrong. Anemic domain models are certainly not a prerequisite for multi-tier applications.

Comment: I am not sure why you are mentioning multi-tier applications but what I am referring to with that @plalx is that rich domain models worked great back in the good old days of thick clients. Nowadays our objects are short lived because of the statelessness of the web and we share a lot of information (not logic) across networks (e.g. APIs, SOAs) so rich domain models don't really play well with that. It is actually preferable in many instances to have anemic domain models for various reasons, one of them being the difficulties the author of the question is facing.

Comment: @Juan I'm mentioning multi-tier, because that is where you need to serialize across the wire in such systems. I do not agree that rich domain models do not play well in these systems. DDD tactical patterns are still used in modern complex distributed systems as of today and there are not so many other approaches that can rival with aggregate roots when it comes to enforcing complex business invariants given a multitude of concurrency scenarios.

Comment: I actually do not see how anemic vs non-anemic is relevant at all? Could you give a concrete example? The fact that logic resides in services rather than stateful objects doesn't make it easier to port that logic to another tier. Stateless services will also not relieve you from having some sort of intermediate representations (e.g. DTO) which gets serialized across the wire. It aso doesn't remove the need for separate ViewModels, which may not have the same shape of these DTOs. If you can just have a single representation at all levels then you are doing basic CRUD.

Comment: CRUD applications will certainly not benefit form a domain model or loose coupling between layers. Just shape your entities, use a generic CRUD application generator and be done with it.

Comment: You are misunderstanding. There is no logic porting. Your definition of multi-tier is different from mine. An example of what Multi-tier means for me is database > Business Logic > Presentation. The premise here is that the user does NOT want to expose his rich domain model. Read the line I wrote that says "I would suggest using Anemic Models in your service implementations." What I am suggesting here is that he has an Anemic Domain model at the service layer which can be reused so he doesn't have to keep creating models. Essentially DTOs with basic high level logic. He can serialize those.

Comment: @Juan Well, there's always a stateless service layer which is the direct client of the domain model (the application layer in DDD tactical patterns), but this layer doesn't contain any business logic and it's contract is not defined in domain terms, but it has nothing to do with domain anemia. You should have such application service layer whether your domain model is anemic or not.